# Static allocator in a templated class issue (invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type)

Tags: c++, templates, static, initialization

***I have edited the original question.***

---

I am trying to use a self-implemented static allocator inside a templated class and I'm getting this error:

`error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type`

I have tried to minimize the code but still preserve the error and this is what I got:

```
template<typename T>
struct allocator_t {
  unsigned char blk[sizeof(T)];
};

template<typename t_value_t, int t_max_nodes>
class foo_c {
private:
  typedef allocator_t<foo_c> bar_allocator_t;
  static bar_allocator_t m_allocator;
};

template<typename t_value_t, int t_max_nodes>
typename foo_c<t_value_t, t_max_nodes>::bar_allocator_t
  foo_c<t_value_t, t_max_nodes>::bar_t::m_allocator;

struct some_t {
  explicit some_t(void) {}
};

void func(void) {
  foo_c<some_t, 10> a;
}
```

The full error stack is this:

```
template_static_example.cc: In instantiation of 'allocator_t<foo_c<some_t, 10> >':
template_static_example.cc:21:2: instantiated from 'foo_c<some_t, 10>'
template_static_example.cc:30:21: instantiated from here
template_static_example.cc:3:30: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'foo_c<some_t, 10>'
```

I have other modules that basically use the same technique and everything is great.

The difference between those modules and the new one I am trying to make is that the new one is templated and indeed, the above code (minus templates) is compiled without errors:

```
template<typename T>
struct allocator_t {
  unsigned char blk[sizeof(T)];
};

class foo_c {
private:
  typedef allocator_t<foo_c> bar_allocator_t;
  static bar_allocator_t m_allocator;
};

foo_c::bar_allocator_t foo_c::m_allocator;

struct some_t {
  explicit some_t(void) {}
};

void func(void) {
  foo_c a;
}
```

Another input I can give is that when I compile with `clang` both are compiled without errors. `g++` however, accepts only the non-templated version.

Comment: Your example can be minimalized as `struct foo { int bar[sizeof(foo)]; };`, you're trying to get at the size of `bar_t` before the end of its definition.

Comment: @user657267 Thanks, I understand that but look at the updated question and try to explain why without templates this is valid.

Comment: @AndyThomas: You still have the same issue. Think of it as a circular dependency; `allocator_t` needs the full definition of `foo_c`  to expand its template, and `foo_c` needs the full definition of `allocator_t` to expand its template.

Comment: @AndyG How does it work without templates then?

Comment: @AndyThomas: There's a couple of things you can do with incomplete types. Unfortunately, trying to get the size of them is not one of them. Please show me an example of the same exact technique working without templates, and I'll show you that you've changed it so that the types are no longer incomplete.

Comment: @AndyG As I said, I've put an example in the question body.

Comment: @AndyThomas: Hmm, I still think the class is incomplete at the point where allocator_t is trying to get its size, but clang and g++ compile no problem. In terms of the templating issue, I still think it's incomplete, but I noticed that if I forward declare allocator_t, then define it later, it works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22403b2c4ca79b70

Comment: And I say that I still think it's incomplete, even in the non-templated case because the size of `allocator_t` depends on the size of `foo_c`, but the size of `foo_c` depends on the size of `allocator_t`. I think that in the non-templated scenario we are basically getting lucky. I think in the forward-declaration-followed by later definition scenario we are basically getting lucky again.

Comment: @AndyG Thank you very much. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that at the heart of things `foo_c` is incomplete because its size depends on the size of `allocator_t`, but `allocator_t` depends on the size of `foo_c`.

If we instead gave `foo_c` a pointer to a `allocator_t<foo_c>`, then things could work, because that is one of the few things we can do with an incomplete type.

```
template<typename t_value_t, int t_max_nodes>
class foo_c {
private:
  typedef allocator_t<foo_c> bar_allocator_t;
  static std::unique_ptr<bar_allocator_t> m_allocator;
};

template<typename t_value_t, int t_max_nodes>
std::unique_ptr<typename foo_c<t_value_t, t_max_nodes>::bar_allocator_t>
  foo_c<t_value_t, t_max_nodes>::m_allocator;
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4935853cf42e896c)

---

It does appear that GCC and Clang [will compile your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22403b2c4ca79b70) as-is so long as you forward declare `allocator_t`, and then place its definition later, but I'm not sure that this is defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your `bar_allocator_t` is declared inside `bar_t`. The allocator is trying to get the size of `bar_t` during compilation:

```
unsigned char blk[sizeof(T)];
```

but it hasn't finished defining the struct yet so it doesn't know what the size is:

```
struct bar_t {
  explicit bar_t(void) {};
  ~bar_t(void);

private:
  typedef allocator_t<bar_t> bar_allocator_t;
  static bar_allocator_t m_allocator; // We don't know the size of `bar_t` here
};
```

I'm not sure what solution will work for you but you probably need to move the allocator outside of the struct, or you could use dynamic memory:

```
template<typename t_value_t, int t_max_nodes>
class foo_c {
   private:
   struct bar_t {
   explicit bar_t(void) {};    
    ~bar_t(void);

  private:
    typedef allocator_t<bar_t> bar_allocator_t;
    static bar_allocator_t * m_allocator;
  };

  bar_t m_root;
};

template<typename t_value_t, int t_max_nodes>
typename foo_c<t_value_t, t_max_nodes>::bar_t::bar_allocator_t *
foo_c<t_value_t, t_max_nodes>::bar_t::m_allocator = 
new typename foo_c<t_value_t, t_max_nodes>::bar_t::bar_allocator_t;
```